# Invocar bot de música en un if en python para discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy programando un bot para discord en python que va por comandos, y me gustaría activar en un if el bot de música para que ponga una canción de youtube en concreto, uniéndose al chat de voz.

Esta es la parte del bot de música:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command
async def play(ctx, url : str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Usa el comando !stop")
        return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name = 'General')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors' : [{
            'key' : 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec' : 'mp3',
            'preferredquality' : '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith("mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))

@client.command
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("El bot no está conectado al canal de voz")

@client.command
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("No hay ninguna canción sonando")

@client.command
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("La canción no está pausada")

@client.command
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
    voice.stop()
```

Lo curioso es que cuando tenía esta parte por separado en un proyecto aparte, sí funcionaba. Ahora que quiero unirlo con el otro bot de comandos, no funciona.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: De momento he conseguido hacer por separado un bot de música que invoque al bot con un /play y una url de youtube, y otro bot que vaya por comandos. Es de frases, y me gustaría que en una de ellas se activara el bot de música. Lo que quiero es unir ambos en un sólo bot de discord

Comment: Esa aclaración debes indicarla _en_ la pregunta, mostrando el código que tienes hasta el momento. Para ello, pulsa en [edit].

Comment: El código tiene 141 líneas, pero puedo pasar la parte del bot de música